# How to make my sidebar, right column, header, footer fixed with scrollable content using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to make a fixed header, footer, sidebar and right column with ads fixed as the content is scrollable.
I tried to make the header and footer outside the flexbox. And the middle page within a wrapper and used flexbox for the 3 columns. I used the sticky property to get my header to be fixed and the fixed property for the sidebar to be fixed. But now the sidebar is overlapping the footer and I don't know why. These are the problems I'm facing.

1. There is a gap at the right side after the page ends horizontally. I tried using width 100% to the entire HTML body but it is not working. There is still a gap.
2. The fixed sidebar is overlapping the footer. I tried fixing the height using calc, but it's not working.
3. The ad column is scrolling after scroll reaches the bottom even though I used sticky property. It's supposed to stay fixed right?
4. Also when I reduce the size of the window horizontally, the right column disappears even though the middle, header and main content reduce the size and get adjusted. I tried to set the width of the entire wrapper to 100%, but the right column is still disappearing.
   I want to avoid using the overflow property and I'm new to flexbox, but I'm not able to understand how to keep make fixed columns.

```css
html body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
#top{
  position:sticky;
  top:0px;
  z-index:1;
}
#header{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #32404d;
  position: relative;
  height: 85px;
}

#header img {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#header p {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-125%);
  color: #dfe9ed;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#nav {
  height: calc(100vh - 90px);
  width: 200px;
  background:#4b5c6e;
  position:fixed;
}

.maincontent{
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 85px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #343e47
}

#heading{
  color:#4b5c6e;
  width: 465px;
  border-bottom: 2.8px solid #313c47;
  font-size: 45px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  font-weight: 500
}

#right{
  width: 180px;
  height: calc(100vh - 90px);
  position: sticky;
  top:85px;
}
.ad{
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: #eaf2fa;
}
#htmlimg{
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#footer-wrapper{
  width: 100%;
}
#footer {
  font-size: small;
  padding: 0.3em;
  height: 40px;
  color:white;
  background: #32404e;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#footer p{
  float:right;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  right: 40px;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header id="top">
    <div id="header">
      <img src="./images/logo1.svg " alt="logo" />
      <p >Welcome Tello</p>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Process</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="maincontent">
      <p id="heading">Welcome to company</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eu arcu quis lorem 
    </p>
      <p>Praesent volutpat tincidunt odio eu laoreet. Nullam pellentesque gravida leo, elementum 
    volutpat.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
      <div class="ad">
        <img id="htmlimg" src="./images/html-5.svg " alt="logo" />
        <img id="cssimg" src="./images/css3.svg " alt="logo" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer-wrapper">
    <footer id="footer"><p>&#169 Tello inc.</p></footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding following styles

```
#right {
        height: calc(100vh - 134px);
    }

#footer-wrapper {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

.maincontent {
    height: calc(100vh - 150px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```